# Vlookup on document with 1m+ rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dataset, vlookup, cross-reference

I'm working on a project with two datasets in excel and I need to cross reference them.

Dataset 1 is around 6,000 and dataset 2 is around 3.5 million records (split over several sheets).

Vlookup obviously won't work over 65,000 rows.

Can anyone suggest a work around or any kind of scripting that may work?

Comment: Why do you say `VLOOKUP()` won't work over 65,000 rows?  What have you tried? Is that because they're split over multiple sheets?

Comment: For excess of 1 million rows, you might be better off using Microsoft Access or a Unix-styel `join` of CSV on the command line.  Excel hasn't had a 65,536 row limit since several versions ago

Comment: You can look up across different sheets using index match and vlookup will also work..

Answer (score 0):

If working in the excel spreadsheets is a must you can do a series of if statements, isna and vlookups.  Not pretty or fast but should work for this case.

```
=IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(<reference>,<some sheet 1>,<column>,FALSE))),"Found",
IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(<reference>,<some sheet 2>,<column>,FALSE))),"Found" ... ,"Not Found"))
```

Edit: added indication of different sheets in vlookups, added not to isna